# Event listener for key down is not being read by my code in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener yet when I press an arrow key no event is fired.

```
document.addEventListener('keyDown', (e) => {
  console.log('key pressed')
})
```

Comment: Can you add more code? some things like `snakeY` are not defined

Comment: its a typo, keydown is meant to be all lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want all lowercase `keydown` for the event name:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {})
```